# If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f$ bounded, then $f_n$ is uniformly bounded proof method question

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n\to f$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$ and $f$ bounded. Show that $f_n$ is uniformly bounded.

This statement is clearly false. But, to provide a counter example to this statement, I passed by a quite strange way using contraposition (because didn't find a counter example for the original statement :( ).

By contraposition, if $f_n\to f$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$ and $f$ bounded $\implies$ $f_n$ is uniformly bounded, then the following must be true as well: not ($f_n$ is uniformly bounded)$\implies$ not$(f_n\to f$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$ and $f$ bounded) or equivalently :

If $f_n$ is not uniformly bounded, then $f_n\to f$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$ or $f$ unbounded.

My question is the following: If I give a counter example to the contraposition statement, does it show as well that the original statement can't hold as well?

If yes, I have the following counter example to the contraposition statement:

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$. Clearly $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly bounded and $f_n\to 0$ pointwise. But, $f$ is bounded. So the contraposition statement is false and the original statement as well.

Comment: Definitely, you should state the definition set of your maps. That would ease to understand if maps are bounded or not for example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contraposition would be, in this case: if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not uniformly bounded, then either $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converges uniformly to $f$ or $f$ is unbounded. Your counter-exampl is not a counter-example to this statement.

That example at the end of your post is not an example, since the convergence is *not* uniform. (I am assuming that this is a sequence of functions with domain $\Bbb R$. If you meant something else, please say so.)

A counter example (again, with domain $\Bbb R$) would be$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }n=1\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$The sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to the null function (which is bounded), but it is not uniformly bounded.

Note that if a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of functions converges uniformly to a bounded function, then, for some $N\in\Bbb N$, $(f_n)_{n\geqslant N}$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: I gave a counter example for the contraposition statement not the original one...

Comment: I've added a new paragraph. What do you think now?

Comment: I see your point about my false negation, thank you! Oh yes, my counter doesn't hold, I see why.. I missed th fact that $f$ must be unbounded (that what I wanted) I wrote it and made the inverse...

Comment: If I take $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}+x$ can it hold as counter example for the contraposition? I'm a little bit confused now.. And the final question, if I give a counter example for the contraposition statement, does it show that the "original" statement can't hold as well?

Comment: The sequence $\left(\frac1n+x\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is *not* a counter example for the contraposition, since your $f$ (the identity function) is unbounded. And, yes, the existence of a counter example for the contraposition is equivalent to the existence of a counter example for the original assertion.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm agree. I'm a little bit confused of "set theory" I've just realised that to get a counter example I have to show that $f_n$ not uniformly bounded $\implies$ $f$ converges uniformly AND $f$ bounded. Is it correct?

Comment: No. As I wrote in my answer, it should be “if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not uniformly bounded, then either $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converges uniformly to $f$ or $f$ is unbounded”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121117/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-daniil).

Answer (score 1):

One key flaw in your question is that the negation of $\{f_n\}$ doesn’t uniformly converge towards $f$ is not that $\{f_n\}$ converges towards $f$ pointwise. Which seems to be what you state in your question.

Also, it should be good that you state the definition set of all your maps.

For example on $I=[0,1]$, the sequence $f_n(x)=n$ doesn’t converge uniformly to the always vanishing map, nor does it pointwise.

Now if a sequence of maps $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ and that $f$ is supposed to be bounded, then $\{f_n\}$ **is eventually uniformly bounded**.

*Note: also the initial statement of the question is true if each of the $f_n$ is supposed to be bounded.*

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was thinking that it might be false as the negation of "uniform convergence" definition is not a "pointwise convergence"